# jQuery -> Javascript (slideToggle) Меню

Tags: javascript, jquery

можно ли библиотеку jquery перевести на js? Требуется сделать открытие/закрытие меню по клику, получилось сделать только через toggle смену класса, но может возможно сделать так же как и в функции slideToggle/SlideUp/slideDown?

```
$("nav div").click(function() {
$("ul").slideToggle();
  $("ul ul").css("display", "none");
});

$('ul li').click(function() {
  $('ul li').slideUp();
  $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
  if($(window).width() > 768) {
    $('ul').removeAttr('style')
  }
});
```

Comment: можно ли библиотеку jquery перевести на js? - Нельзя.

Comment: Добавлю. Нельзя, потому что jquery и так на js!